# Flow javascript class properties get overwritten with undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowtype

I have two classes

```
export class Model {
_id: ID

  constructor(arg : ID | string | Object) {
   if (typeof arg === 'object') this.loadObject
 }


  loadObject(obj: Object) {
    Object.assign(this, obj)
    // using a for loop to assign keys does not work with flow
  }
}

export class User extends Model {
_id: ID
username: string
//...other properties
}
```

When I call `new Model(userObject)` all the properties get defined. But when I call `new User(userObject)` only some properties get defined, some remain undefined. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You forget to call `this.loadObject` and you need to call `super` in `User`'s `constructor`.

Try this:

```
export class Model {
  _id: ID

  constructor(arg: ID | string | Object) {
    if (typeof arg === 'object') this.loadObject(arg)
  }

  loadObject(obj: Object) {
    Object.assign(this, obj)
  }
}

export class User extends Model {
  _id: ID
  username: string

  constructor(arg) {
    super(arg)
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: still does not work for me.. User object is right after `this.loadObject()` in Model's constructor, but wrong if logged after `super(arg)` in User's constructor.

Comment: Fun fact some properties are initialized and some are not (and does not depend on the type of the property). 
The argument object comes from a JSON, though it should not matter..

Comment: JSON does not matter. If a give an object with all user properties still shows them undefined.

Comment: Then I have no clue whats the problem. It works for me.. I create a User (`new User({ prop1: 123 })` and in User constructor after super call I logged: `console.log(this.prop1)` and I see `123`

Comment: I solved using flow-remove-types before compiling with babel. I think it's a @babel/preset-flow issue. When it sees class properties adds `Object.defineProperty` after the constructor